# ruby equivalent of python izip_longest

Tags: python, ruby

I am trying to learn ruby. 
At this moment I have a list of lists, and I would like to the equivalent of the following python code:

```
import itertools
l = [[1,2], [3], [10, 20, -4, 5]]
list(itertools.izip_longest(*l, fillvalue='NaN'))
```

The result is:

```
[(1, 3, 10), (2, 'NaN', 20), ('NaN', 'NaN', -4), ('NaN', 'NaN', 5)]
```

The number of lists in the list `l` can be different. Is there a easy way of accomplishing the same in ruby?

Comment: Different languages have different idioms, Ruby has arrays, map, join, to_str to convert to string, lambda; might be useful if you explain what you want to do...

Comment: what I want to do is exactly what is show in python. I have several lists of values and will this will join each of the elements with a `,` pairwise, if a list is smaller than the others the corresponding elements will be replaced by an empty string.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill: While that's true in general, they're not _that_ different in this case. Python calls them lists, map, join, str, and lambda, and map and str are functions rather than methods, but otherwise they're basically the same (which isn't surprising, because most of those, Ruby borrowed either straight from Python, or from the same sources as Python).

Comment: As a side note, throwing all this extra Python-specific complexity into a question that has nothing to do with anything but `zip_longest` is just going to scare away 90% of the Ruby wizards who would know the answer like the back of their hands. And since the Python code is not very Pythonic (using `lambda` instead of `def`, but then assigning the result to a name anyway? avoiding the trivial `map(str, x)` right before using a more complex `map` call? adding extra parens in places they aren't needed?), even some Python wizards who know a bit of Ruby will be scared off too.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill I accept that using an exact equivalent of izip_longest might not be the best thing to do here, thats why I have a complete example of what I was trying to do.

Comment: @abarnert I did not try to add any extra parenthesis. Which ones you think are extra that aren't needed?

Comment: @skeept: `join((str(i) for i in x))` is the same thing as `join(str(i) for i in x)`. (Although `join(map(str, x))` is probably simpler.) But the point is, that isn't relevant to your question at all, and no matter how you write it, it makes your question look more complicated, especially to people who don't know Python very well, so… why include it at all? Why not just show what `izip_longest` does, with an example, and ask how to do that?

Comment: Looking again, it appears that you are trying to convert from row-major (array of rows) to column-major format (array of columns) with a rule for filling missing values so all column vectors have same length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct counterpart for `izip_longest` in Ruby standard library.

```
l = [[99,2], [3], [10, 20, -4, 5]]
n = l.map{ |x| x.size }.max
(0...n).map { |i| l.map { |x| x.fetch(i, 'NaN') } }
# => [[99, 3, 10], [2, "NaN", 20], ["NaN", "NaN", -4], ["NaN", "NaN", 5]]
```